# receipt service.net

Tags: .net

I have a website that serves few businesses. For each one of them I would like to be able to print a valid receipt when they are getting money from their clients. Is there a service or a module I could use? free is better!
I'm using aspx in vs2010 .

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information.  What, **exactly**, do you want the service or module to do?  You can build a receipt in html, as a pdf, etc.

Comment: Hi. I need the service to know all the IRS legal information needed to create a receipt. for example; is it ok to give two receipts the same number?? NO.

Comment: There is no such thing. Receipts are very custom to the particular application and extremely easy to do and pretty much the only "rule", which you identified, is as much for your own accounting as reporting.  Go buy something at a convenience store and look at that receipt.  It will show the date/time, transaction id, list of goods purchased, purchase amount, a total, and how it was paid.  It will also have the name of the company and, potentially, an address.  Beyond that you would just add purchaser information (if available) like their name or whatever else you need to identify them.

Comment: Ok, if so then I think I'll just do it myself. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like [SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/) for this, that way the user has the option to download the receipt as well as printing it off.

There is plenty of [Documetation](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/Guide.html) and [Tutorials](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/Tutorials.html) for the Library and it is very simple to use.

Hope this helps

EDIT: Given your response to Chris's Comment then my answer can be potentially disregarded, The library while it will allow you to create a PDF Receipt it knows nothing of your other requirements, once you have these fulfilled then SharpPDF could still be an option to output your receipt.